# Can't find Libgtkmm-3.0.so.1

Tags: 64-bit, gtk, libraries, anjuta

After moving to a new computer and reinstalling all that I had on my old one, I can compile a C++ program that's using GTK+3.0 in Anjuta but when I try to run it, I get the message

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-3.0.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've spent a bit of time searching for an answer to this and have even reinstalled the package with improvement.   What am I missing here?   I find a link (I think this is correct term) to this file in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.  Do I need to copy this link somewhere else, update an environment variable (`PKG_CONFIG_PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), or what?   (Both of the mentioned variables are currently empty.)

My old computer was a 32-bit system and this new one is 64-bit.  I have only copied files - I have reinstalled all needed packages and programs.  I did copy the Anjuta files when I copied the source directories.

Any suggestions to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working today!  I believe this issue is related to my move to my new setup because the old laptop was a 32-bit processor and my new system is a 64-bit system.

I deleted all of the files and folders associated with Anjuta, leaving only my source and class files.  I defined a new project, added the appropriate libraries, and the build and compile worked fine.

I have an issue with Anjuta running the program without debugging (it's looking for the executable in the debug directory but I built the code in the default configuration) but the program works if I run it manually.